# Hover effect in bootstrap navbar not working

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a navbar with bootstrap and the hover effect in css isn't working and i added the hover pseudo class to my anchor tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <style>
         li a:hover{
    background-color: green;}
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse mynav">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#"  style="color: white" class="mouseHover">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" style="color: white">About</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" style="color: white">Work</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" style="color: white" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which bootstrap are you using? Please add the correct tag for your bootstrap version. Then add the correct Bootstrap CSS to the head element. Also move your code to a code snippet (**Ctrl+M**) that can be run.

Comment: You should include bootstrap stylesheet including correct version in the head part

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user is trying to answer his own questions immediately as someone else, but looks like he forgot to change an account :joy:

Comment: @ulou I'm new here on stack overflow and i actually had this challenge but couldn't find the answer here, so when I finally found it, i thought it would be nice posting it here to help someone else. I don't know if i broke any rules but if I did, do what you think is best. cheers  :-)

Comment: No worries. I was just little confused, cause you answered to yourself in 2nd person. Usually is better practice to edit question and at the bottom add smth like "My current solution" and smth like "Currently I did this in this way, but I feel like is not the best one". Cheers :->

Answer (score -2):

when you want to customize bootstrap elements use the !important attribute in your css like so

```
li a:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid blueviolet !important; 
background-color: ;
```

}

Comment: Down-voted for following reason: Anwser is technical incorrect. There is no reason to use the `!important;-nuke` which can cause a varity of unwated behavior by raising the specificity weight. You just need to declare custom CSS after the Bootstrap link or simply place the bootstrap link at the very top and the custom css will overwrite the bootstrap styling.